# Slow procedure in Indesign with certain 80 pages long story? Any fixes?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I have a document which has about 30 pages of images and portfolio at first and then about 80 pages long story starts.

When I highlight text to select in this story text frames, it make application no responding near 3 or 4 minutes.

*Changed font: no fix

*Turned off document preflight: no fix

*Cleared greps in paragraph style: no fix

When I go through paragraphs with arrow keys and edit it, there is no issues, until selection of characters, and I again have to wait.

Don't know what's the cause could be. Any idea?

Comment: 80 pages isn't much. I've had 600+ pages documents on a 10 year old computer without that much of a delay. To test if it's your computer or your document which is causing the problem, you could try making a new document and inserting the 80-page text. If it works without problems, there must be something buggy in your document causing the problem.

Comment: Alternately, you could test to see if the *images* are the problem by switching display performance to Fast Mode (the one where you see image frames with no image as a proxy for your placed images) and if you switch to that mode, save once, and then try accessing the text frames again and it runs at a more normal speed... you have too many large in-line images!

Comment: @Wolff It also amazed me too... I have a lot of docs with too many images inline, anchored or free form... but this issue didn't met them... by accepting you there must be som probs in doc! I test your fix ASAP! thank you wolff.

Comment: @GerardFalla Thanks for your solution! but I already and always using this feature and even clear all images individual displaying modes to follow doc fast mode.

Answer (score 2):

1. I am agreeing with **@Danielillo**'s answer above ***exactly*** (*and* would like to know *why* someone has downvoted his answer as it is *exactly* correct).
2. I used to use this technique to produce *very* large documents (user manuals from 30 pages through 1000+ for multi-million dollar very complex tools with PLC interfaces and a huge number of valves and settings) which included both high res images and screengrabs in large quantity.
3. Break the document up into separate files, linked through a "book" file, work easily and make a more logical final structure - not just as an e-pub (as Danielillo correctly said earlier) but also as a structured PDF - if you have a TOC the PDF will have integrated hyperlinks, and with chapters in a book you get really nicely structured navigation out of this.
4. This also allows better conceptual structuring of your document, which though it may seem like more work up front, will save you later struggles during revision.

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer of @Danielillo, but it seems to be a workaround rather than a true solution. 80 pages is nothing and shouldn't cause 3-4 minutes freeze. I've made lots of novels with 400-800 pages in one long story without problems. There must be some other problem causing the freeze.

Comment: @Wolff Does your novel has 30 pages with high res images full size?

Comment: @Danielillo, no it seldom has so many hi-res images - you are right. But the "bug" occurs when selecting text with the mouse. InDesign is pretty good at disregarding pages which are not in view. Having heavy images in one part of a document, shouldn't interfere with text flow in another part of the document. I might be wrong of course, but I suspect that there is something in particular causing the problem for the OP.

Comment: @Wolff - that depends a huge amount on ***how*** those images are placed: if many or most of them are *in-line in the text,* guess what... slow-down city. Every ***touch*** of the threaded text-frames containing the inline images will be damned close to a freeze. for me, I've always made it a practise to break image-heavy document sections out as separate chapters and "book 'em" even if there's no TOC and the enduser won't "see" the booking at all - makes a more manageable file.

Comment: @GerardFalla, that could be the explanation. i wouldn't in-line large images for that exact reason. I'm not against using chapters at all. I just don't think it's the "true" solution in this case.

Comment: hey there guys, images here not hi res and they are not-complex very simple vector arts in eps format and are 18x18 cm dimensions. also I've deleted them and tested file but still text bugging!

Comment: Images are not inline... I've placed them in center of pages... and also while I did placing them, there was not any issue and even resizing and repositioning em in frames caused to probs.

Comment: ... and about dan's solution. lets upvote it so its gets hi! ;)

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote Danielillo's answer either, and to help counteract the negativity, I will also upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Try dividing the file into different chapters and create a book

> The advantages of using books instead of a single big InDesign document are:
>
> ✔ If the document is an ePub, the e-reader will be faster at loading each chapter because it won’t need to load the entire book
>
> ✔ You can link an InDesign document to many books
>
> ✔ Many people can work on the project at the same time (one for each InDesign file)
>
> ✔ **Documents are lighter, so you need less power to work on them**
>
> ✔ It’s easier to move around chapters/sections of your documents (let’s say you want to move chapter 5 to the beginning of your book, with a book file you can do it with a single drag and drop)

Source https://redokun.com/blog/indesign-book

Comment: I think your answer is ***spot***-*bloody-on*, for the record.

Comment: Thanks dan, It's a good solution but at this project my hands are tight! I'm afraid the boss let me to do that, while the reasonably document is not so big in pages.